# Smart Mass Update - File Import - Append Data Field Value Instead of Update\Replace

Tags: field-update, import, mass-action

I'm new to Salesforce & ZaapIT's Smart Mass Update.  I'm using Smart Mass Update to import contact records via CSV files.  I am looking for an option to append existing values in a data field during an import rather than replacing the existing data in the target field.

I have a text box (or even a multipick list) in Salesforce.  Call it field Alpha.  Any existing data in field Alpha is removed and replaced with the freshly imported CSV file data when I use Smart Mass Update.

I want to leave the existing data in Alpha during the import and have the freshly imported CSV add to what is already there.

Example:

- In Salesforce I have 500 unique contact records each with a text data
  field labeled Alpha.
- The Alpha field is blank for 250 of these unique records
- The Alpha field has the value FOX for 200 unique records
- The Alpha field has the value BROWN for 50 unique records
- I have a CSV file with the value QUICK that is going to be imported
  to the Alpha field for all 500 contact records

When I import the file using Smart Mass Update in this scenario, the end result (which I don't want) is that all 500 contact records will only show the value QUICK in the Alpha field.  All previously existing data is deleted during the import.

What I'm really looking for in this scenario would be these results:

- Alpha field for the 250 blank records = QUICK
- Alpha field for the 200 records with FOX = FOX QUICK
- Alpha field for the 50 records with BROWN = BROWN QUICK

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE.  Please take a moment to read [ask] and take the [tour].  If you want to use ZaapIT, you'll have to check with the vendor.  If ZaapIT can't do what you need, it's possible to build a Flow to do this process and you could use any data import tool.

Comment: Thank you @DavidCheng.  I will check with ZaapIT.  When  you say build a "Flow" ... I notice you used a capital letter.  Is a Flow a menu option in Salesforce?  I did a search and found something by Trailhead called Flow Builder.  Is that it?

Thank you again.